# Quick way to alert the values of all input elements in a form?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have a form with about 10+ input elements in it... For testing, I'd like to alert all their values... Is there a quicker way than this:

```
var f = document.getElementById('myForm').getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
alert(f[0].name + ' ' + f[0].value);
alert(f[1].name + ' ' + f[1].value);
alert(f[2].name + ' ' + f[2].value);
... and so on...
```

Comment: Put that in a loop then it will be shorter and maybe quicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#for_Statement) for that.

```
var f = document.getElementById('myForm').getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    alert(f[i].name + ' ' + f[i].value);
```

If you are just testing/debugging things, I'd recommend using your browser's console. Using Chrome or Firefox + [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can call the `console.log` method and then drill down into your object. This tends to be a bit easier to manage in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe com bile the strings adding "\n" between them so you get one alert.

Comment: Doh! I'm surprised that this did not occur to me... Looping the alert makes for cleaner code, with the same end result... Thanks... :-)

Comment: Probably better to loop over `f.elements` so that the value of all form controls can be seen (though a good DOM inspector is better in this case).

Answer (score 2):

The smart way to do this is to instead install an extension similar to the [Web Developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), then use ***Forms*** -> ***View Form Information*** to see the values of all inputs.

[Google Chrome version is here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm).